# An elementary introduction of Colombeau's generalized function theory

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, schwartz-distributions, reference-request

Hello, I am wondering whether anyone know an elementary reference for Colombeau's theory on the multiplication of distributions? I encountered the problem of the square of Delta function. I need a rigorous treatment of this object. Through my previous question, I notice that Colombeau's theory might help. Thank you in advance for any points. :-)

Comment: Maybe at the same time keep in mind the possibility to define multiplication provided the wave front sets are transversal (which is not the case for deltas being singular in every direction). In this way you do not go out of the standard theory. Colombeau's theory seems slightly too large to be really useful (my personal opinion)

Comment: @Prof. D'Ancona, thank you very much for your comments. I am considering the case $\delta_0^2(x)$ on the real line $R$. In this case, do you think that the wave front sets are transversal? Sorry for my unfamiliarity of 

Comment: Unfortunately not, on $R$ my remark is useless.

Comment: @Prof. D'Ancona, thank you very much. That's why I ask this question. :-) 

Comment: How is this related to algebraic geometry?

Comment: @Angelo, Sorry, I made a mistake. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for repeating myself, but as you can see on the nLab [here](http://nlab.mathforge.org/nlab/show/distribution#colombeau_10), Colombeau himself has written an elementary introduction to his theory, mainly for people who are interested in applications:

Jean François Colombeau: "Multiplication of distributions. A tool in mathematics, numerical engineering and theoretical physics."

See this [review](http://www.zentralblatt-math.org/zmath/en/advanced/?q=an:00108533&type=pdf&format=complete) in the Zentralblatt Mathematik. This will also give you a hint if this approach is suitable to your problem (BTW: what is the application you are thinking about?).

Comment: @Tim van Beek,thank you very much for your comments. I browsed nLab, it is very informative and helpful. But I still could get an easier introduction for this theory. I will have a look of JF Colombeau's book that you recommended. As for my application, consider the heat equation with random noise. I am calculating the second moments of the solution. If the initial data is a Delta function, then the initial data for the second moment will be the square of delta. That's where my problem comes from. :-)

Comment: Alright, but in this case I'd recommend to ask an expert of stochastic differential equations if this approach is valid, or if a different approach using e.g. Wick products would be more appropriate (see for example Oksendahl et. alt., "Stochastic Parital Differential Equations").

What you are dealing with here is a well known problem, both from quantum field theory and from stochastic PDE, with different solutions - and the approach of Colombeau is IMHO not the best one :-) (But, again, this depends on the problem you try to solve.)

Comment: @Anand: for your application, you are much better off just taking the second moment to be infinite on the initial slice. Heat equation is infinitely smoothing, so at any later time the solution is Schwartz, random noise will not change the integrability by that much. My hunch is that for any reasonable definition, the limit $t\to 0^+$ of your second moment will necessarily blow-up. That said, you should also look at some of the literature on the Bohmian methods in Quantum Mechanics. I vaguely remember there being some similar issues, unfortunately I don't recall the reference. 

Comment: @Willie Wong, thank you very much for your comment. What I derived (second moment) is something like $\frac{e^{-x^2/t}}{2\pi t}$, while another known result is $\frac{e^{-x^2/t}}{2\pi t}+c \frac{e^{-x^2/(2t)}}{\sqrt{2\pi t}}$ with some constant $c$. It is true that in either case, the results blow up at $t=0$. But which one is right? Does the system has multiple second moments? Our result looks more like $\delta_0^2(x)$ for $t=0$. I will have a look of Bohmian's method. Thank you very much!

Comment: Anand, could you say what you mean by "second moment"? I am under the impression that the second moment of the delta function is zero.

Comment: @Tim van Beek, Thank you for your comment. As I mentioned in the comment to Willie Wong, I met this problem due to two different results. One is well known. Ours is different the known one slightly. I couldn't find the problem. I guess the problem might come from the square of delta function. That's why I am asking for a rigorous definition for that. Thank you. :-) 